# DateTime.Now showing Time two times

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime

I have a strange problem in my machine. When i take the DateTime it shows time two times.

Do anyone know why is the date coming like this?

```
DateTime.Now returns date as 05/04/2015 12:00 AM 12:00:00 AM
```

**Note: 12:00 AM *and* 12:00:00 AM**

Please help me. I want to return the data as DateTime. I cannot format it(format even though removes the second time).

I have searched enough over the internet and it always shows timespan, time difference. It does not show exact my problem.

Here is a screenshot of what you get and tell me how this is happening?
 [image]

Comment: That is weird. Can you please paste an actual block of code where this happens?

Comment: It is the display of the datetime which is incorrect, not the datetime. You should check the date and time settings in the Windows control panel.

Comment: Where are you seeing that value ? in debugger ? `DateTime.Now` returns a `DateTime`, which doesn't have any format associated with it.

Comment: string s = DateTime.Now.ToString(); This returns 06/03/2015 07:40 PM 7:40:12 PM How is this possible??

Comment: Looks like you're formatting it as a string somewhere and got one too many `H:mm:ss`

Comment: What does `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);` print on your machine? And what locale do you have? (check with `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`)

Comment: Just see the screenshot and decide whether this question is genuine or not? I don't know why people would be so mad at a question like this when someone struggles so badly.

Comment: Please test this on a console application and show us the output of `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);`! Debugger view is one thing, but the actual output matters.

Comment: Im in an asp.net application i need to pass 3 dates as datetime to the DB. But it throws error saying format issue even though i pass it as Datetime. I can get you a console screenshot

Comment: Console shows the date correctly.

Comment: If the issue occurs when you pass the `DateTime` to a DB then include that code and the error that you get.

Answer (score 5):

Returns it to what?  `DateTime.Now` returns a `DateTime`, not a formatted `string`.  If you're looking at it as text, then something is converting it to a `string`.  The problem then is wherever that is happening.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I can think of that you might get that result:

1. The current-culture may have been modified to emit that format.

   For example:

   ```
   var customCulture = (CultureInfo) new CultureInfo("en-US").Clone();
   customCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "hh:mm tt h:mm:ss tt";
   System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;

   var s = DateTime.Now.ToString();
   Console.WriteLine(s);  // "6/3/2015 10:17 AM 10:17:59 AM"
   ```
2. The date and time settings in the Windows control panel may have been altered with a custom setting.  This is found under: `"Change date,time, or, number formats"` - `"Formats" tab` - `"Additional settings"` - `"Time"`.

   For example, if you change the "Long time" format as follows:

   [image: control panel]

   Then you will get the same format with just the default culture settings.

Since you are seeing the result in the Visual Studio debugger, #2 is more likely.

Comment: No, i checked the time settings.. but its just normal with just one time.

Comment: And what about #1?  What do you see as the output of `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern`?